# Store the last line of a paragraph (p) as a variable to be used in JQuery

Tags: jquery

We are working with an extremely limited system where we are not able to natively edit the underlying HTML code. We can, however, adjust the system using CSS and Javascript / JQuery.

Our goal is to modify the private messaging system when someone receives an award. We have no options to style the text in any way so it's all plain text with line breaks. Our idea is to add one final line containing a 'tag' of sorts which will be used internally to detect the specific award someone has won and theme the response based on that.

```
<p class"message__content">
Congratulations!<br>
You have won an award<br>
#specificawardtag
</p>
```

The script that I am trying to write needs to be able to store this tag as a string, and that string can then be used in other areas of the script. For example, the same string is also the title of a .png file that is referenced. I can then run a loop for each award message and the right content is displayed dynamically.

I have been able to get the script to work purely by defining each award separately but that isn't exactly sustainable or efficient. Any ideas of how I can achieve this properly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ((document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('\"conversation?with=bot-account\"') > -1) {
      $('p.message__content').each(function(index, value) {
      var content = $(this).innerText();
      var tagLastline = $(this).substr(this.lastIndexOf("\n")+1);
      alert(tagLastline);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works, your code looks totally ok. Maybe won't be hurt from some syntax sugar. Also instead of detecting string `conversation?with=bot-account` I would put some body class like `<body class="page-conversation">`. It is more explicit and will continue working if URLs change.

```js
$(function () {
    if ($(`[href*="${CSS.escape('conversation?with=bot-account')}"]`).length){
      const tags = [...$('p.message__content')].map(p => p.textContent.trimEnd().match(/[^\n]+$/)?.[0]);
      console.log(tags);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="path/conversation?with=bot-account">conversation</a>
<p class="message__content">
blah<br>
#tag1
</p>
<p class="message__content">
blah<br>
#tag2
</p>
```